# CSS hover is not working . Where am I getting it wrong?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with basic css hover. I don't understand why it's not working.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

i {
  color: #319a31;
  font-size: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
}

.col-sm-6:hover i {
  color: #ff8533;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
    <img src="images/electrical-construction.jpg" class="img-responsive img1">
    <i class="fas fa-cloud-sun-rain text-center sun1"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check again... It is working

Comment: Definitely works. Maybe clear cache and try again?

Comment: Works fine on Edge, Chrome, Firefox and even IE11 on Windows10. What browser/system are you using?

Comment: It seems to work fine, but can't answer 100% without your image not being broken. If you have any css on your image tags that you didn't include, it's possible your issue is the layering of the elements. (less likely with a jpg since you probably wouldn't layer an image format without transparency over other elements, but still possible)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's working i guess . Restart your browser or try to run this code in a different browser.